# java aio may have bugs in the Mac

Tags: java, macos, aio

I developed an open source framework smart-socket, all aspects are still quite satisfactory, except that there is a strange phenomenon can not find a solution.

This project in Windows, Linux system can be stable operation, but the operation under the Mac will lead to the system run around the restart.

Project address: https://github.com/smthing/smart-socket

Download to the local start after the first P2PServer, and then start P2PMultiClient, running on the Mac for a minute or two should crash.

Comment: I don't want to create an account on gitee.com,,,

Comment: add code in your question. Don't refer people to external sources, since that usually demotivates people to answer your question. Especially if that site requires a registration.

Comment: @Seer OK, this time it didn't asked me to authenticate.

Comment: @Seer also it might be a good idea to have documentation in english instead of chinese!

Comment: @FrankK you can review code，my English is not good